# Вычисление интеграла методом левых прямоугольников

Tags: java

```
Public static double rectangle(int x1[],double f[],int n) { 
        double n1=n;
        double h=(n1-1)/n1;
        double Integral=0.0;
        for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)  { 
           Integral+=h*(f[i]);
         } 
        System.out.println(Integral);
        return Integral;
     } 

public void static main(String[] args) { 
int a=0,b=4;
        int n=b-a+1;
        int x1[]=new int[n];
        double f[]=new double[n];
        String format = "|%1$-16s|%2$-16s|\n";
        System.out.format(format, "----------------", "----------------");
        System.out.format(format, "      y(x)      ", "        x       ");
        System.out.format(format, "----------------", "----------------");
        int k=0;
        for (int x = a; x <= b;x++)  { 

            System.out.format("|%15.7e |%15d |%n",Math.pow(Math.E, x)-x*x*x,x);
            System.out.format(format, "----------------", "----------------");
               x1[k] = x;
               f[k] = Math.pow(Math.E, x) - x * x * x;
            if(k<=b-1) k += 1;

         } 
        rectangle(x1,f,n);
 }
```

Сделал вычисление интеграла методом левых прямоугольников. Значение отличается от значений интеграла в калькуляторе где-то на 1-1,5.Таблицу вывести и заполнить массивы требовалось по условию. Я точно правильно описал алгоритм? А то может из-за какой-то ошибки возникает такая большая погрешность. Допустим, на отрезке [0;4] калькулятор из интернета выдает −10.40184996685576,а у меня -11.36718009302273. На отрезке [0;5] вместо −8.836840897423393 выводит 7.670153321915132.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, ты считаешь по методу левых треугольников, поэтому тебе не нужно высчитывать интеграл правой границы (`<= b` -> `< b`).

Во-вторых, так значение `h` не считается, `h = (правая_гр - левая_гр) / кол-во_отрезков`, в данном случае `(4-0) / 4 = 1`, а не `(4-1) / 4`.

Вот математика:
[image: Показательная инфа с сайта-калькулятора]

Отсюда видны закономерности, а также график, который наглядно показывает, почему погрешность больше, чем даже предполагал это ты.

С применением предложенных изменений ответом будет ~`-4.8`.

К стилю кода есть множество вопросов - это и нарушения в области отступов, и бесполезные переменные, и функция с непредсказуемым (по названию) функционалом. Я бы переписал это так:

```
public static double getIntegralValueByLeftRectangle(double funcValues[], int from, int to) { 
    int intervalsCount = funcValues.length; // кол-во интервалов можно определить из кол-ва переданных значений ф-ции
    double h = getIntervalLength(from, to, intervalsCount);
    double integral = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < intervalsCount; i++)  { 
        integral += h * funcValues[i];
    }
    return integral;
} 

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int from = 0, to = 4, intervalsCount = 4;
    double intervalLength = getIntervalLength(from, to, intervalsCount);
    double funcValues[] = new double[intervalsCount];
    String format = "|%1$-16s|%2$-16s|\n";
    System.out.format(format, "----------------", "----------------");
    System.out.format(format, "      y(x)      ", "        x       ");
    System.out.format(format, "----------------", "----------------");
    double leftX = from;
    for (int i = 0; i < intervalsCount; i++, leftX += intervalLength)  { 
        System.out.format("|%15.7e |%15.2f |%n", Math.pow(Math.E, leftX) - leftX * leftX * leftX, leftX); // 15d -> 15.2f
        System.out.format(format, "----------------", "----------------");
        funcValues[i] = Math.pow(Math.E, leftX) - leftX * leftX * leftX;
    } 
    System.out.println(getIntegralValueByLeftRectangle(funcValues, from, to));
} 

public static double getIntervalLength(double from, double to, int intervalsCount) {
    return (to - from) / intervalsCount;
}
```

Вывод:

```
|----------------|----------------|
|      y(x)      |        x       |
|----------------|----------------|
|  1.0000000e+00 |              0 |
|----------------|----------------|
|  1.7182818e+00 |              1 |
|----------------|----------------|
| -6.1094390e-01 |              2 |
|----------------|----------------|
| -6.9144631e+00 |              3 |
|----------------|----------------|
-4.807125149422641
```

Comment: спасибо, что так подробно расписал.